# AST Deserialize Issue, input is not a PCH file

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm currently taking over someone's else project who was in a different country. He is using MumbleKit in his project, however when i try building the project, these errors occurred.

> error: input is not a PCH file: '/Users/kai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestBuild-bivflkvgwypsqidilllttbdfyjjq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/70367429320928002/CELT-0.7.pch.gch'
>   fatal error: file '/Users/kai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestBuild-bivflkvgwypsqidilllttbdfyjjq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/70367429320928002/CELT-0.7.pch.gch' is not a valid precompiled PCH file

Now, i have tried fixing the header path file and cleaning the project and deleting derived folder's content, still this error occurred. I believe xcode is trying to find a pch file but this .gch is being created instead. How can i prevent this .gch from being created in the derived folder? Or how do i fix this in general since i don't really deal with 3rd party project dependency before.

EDIT : I believe this error is coming from the 3rd party Mumble kit, CELT-0.7 project

Comment: It's quite hard to help because this error sound really specific. Please check "How to include mumblekit" here: https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumblekit Did you add the build phase at the right position? Maybe you have to readd mumblekit and then every reference is working.

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded the project a fresh, tried to build it, didn't work, figure it was coming from mumblekit, deleted mumblekit and reclone it from github, followed the instruction by updating the submodule and the header and adding dependency but it is still giving me this error. From what i can tell, the building process doesn't even go to the actual project code but fails at building CELT in mumblekit.

Comment: I've just created a test empty new project and added mumble kit and integrate it and the error still occurs so i'm guessing the mumble kit is the problem

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I've found the solution, Mumble kit's CELT project have a file : Base.xcconfig.
There is a variable, GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER, initially it was set to YES, after set it NO, that fixed it. Though it will be nice if someone would explain to me what it does exactly.